# Convert a long string into a matrix, cleaning it

Tags: python, regex, string, numpy, matrix

I have a large text file which is just a very long string. It is a huge block of text.

The original maker of this file tried to make this a "matrix" by setting `\n` tabs after a certain count of letters.

```
string = "adfajdslfkajsddf&&adfadfladfsjdfl\nadk...fhaldkfjahsdf"
```

Using regular expressions with the module `re` (possibly), how can I input each character of this massive string into the matrix it was originally supposed to be?

Also, there are certain garbage characters in the string, like "&" and "#" and "{". Is there a standard module to use?

I imagine one could take the original string, break it up into a couple of strings based on where the '\n' marker is, and then place these strings somehow into a numpy ndarray by each individual character of the string.

Comment: Please provide an expected output and do not forget to mention the code you already tried to develop.

Comment: what are the valid or the invalid chars?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Anything that is a letter/integer is valid. All other symbols are garbage to be removed. This should be each to do with `re` and an if statement, iterating throughout the entire string.

Comment: So is it all punctuation that is junk?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see what you're getting at. isalpha() is probably the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a couple of way, you can check each char seeing if it is alphanumeric:

```
stg = "abcde123]\nefghi456}\njk{lmn789"
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([ch for line in stg for ch in line if ch.isdigit() or ch.isalpha()])
```

Or if all the junk is punctuation you can `str.translate`:

```
from string import punctuation

junk = {ord(ch):"" for ch in punctuation + "\n"}


arr = np.array(list(stg.translate(junk)))
```

Both will give you a flat list:

```
['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' '1' '2' '3' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' '4' '5' '6' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' '7' '8' '9']
```

If you want multidimensional arrays, you can split on the newline:

```
arr = np.array([[ch for ch in line ] for line in stg.translate(junk).split()])

arr = np.array([[ch for ch in line if ch.isdigit() or ch.isalpha()] for line in stg.split()])
```

Which will give you:

```
[['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' '1' '2' '3']
 ['e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' '4' '5' '6']
 ['j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' '7' '8' '9']]
```

For python2 the `translate` is a little different:

```
from string import punctuation
import numpy as np


stg = "abcde123]\nefghi456}\njk{lmn789"
arr = np.array([[ch for ch in line ] for line in stg.translate(None, punctuation).split()])
print(arr)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a `dict` argument to `.translate()` *is* supported in Python 2, but only as a method of `unicode` strings.  So `stg=u"...."` would do it,  or `stg = stg.decode('utf-8')`